# What is the difference between round() and ceil() in java

Tags: java, methods, package

I am wondering what may be the difference between the two methods round() and ceil() in the package Math in java and why they don't return an integer?

Comment: Did you read their documentation?

Comment: Yes, but didn't get much
@Tunaki

Comment: rounds up half a faction, and ceil rounds up any fraction.  They don't return an int or long as the `double` value could be larger than the largest possible long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math.round` is underspecified, and I believe its behavior has actually changed in the past -- see http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6430675 -- but generally speaking it behaves like [`RoundingMode.HALF_UP`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_UP), which has an extensive table of its differences from `RoundingMode.CEILING` or `RoundingMode.FLOOR`.

Answer (score 1):

Round will convert 3.3 into 3 while ceil will convert the same into 4. Hope you understood.

Comment: That's not a precise description of the behaviour. In fact it would allow quite a lot of misinterpretations.

Comment: so round is like floor() ?

Comment: @Paul
can you correct this misunderstanding sir, Paul

Comment: @Razorbolt that's not how SO works, if the answer isn't appropriate, it should be removed and will be downvoted. And in fact this answer needs severe editing of the entire content to be of any use.

Comment: round removes the decimal part i.e. it converts 3.3 into 3.0 and 4.7 into 4.0. While ceil adds up to the next whole number i.e. 3.3 into 4.0 and 4.7 into 5.0.